# Scrapy - Spiders gets stuck after yielding request and callback function is not working

Tags: web-scraping, scrapy, python-3.5, twisted

I have been working on Scrapy from past 2 to 3 weeks with the following dependencies:

1. Python 2.7
2. Twisted 17.9.0
3. Lxml 4.1.1
4. Cryptography 2.1.4

Now, I have upgraded my dependencies to

1. Python 3.5.2
2. Twisted 17.9.0
3. Lxml 4.2.1
4. Cryptography 2.2.2

After updating my dependencies, my spiders gets stuck.
It gets stuck after yielding requests, also callback function is not initiated and spider moves to an infinite waiting state.

**ScraperRequestCode**:

```
def start_requests(self):
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    driver.get(**)
    urls = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[contains(@class, 'media__item')]//a")
    time_list = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//span[contains(@class, 'timestamp--time')]")
    index = 0
    for url in urls:
        url_href = str(url.get_attribute('href')).replace('http:', 'https:')
        media_url = url.find_element_by_xpath("./*").get_attribute('src')
        text = url.find_element_by_xpath("./*").get_attribute('alt')
        try:
            time = time_list[index].get_attribute('title')
            time = str(datetime.datetime.strptime(str(time).lstrip(), '%b %d, %Y %I:%M%p'))
            index = index + 1
        except IndexError:
            time = ''
            pass
        if url_href != "None":
            count = News.objects.filter(url__icontains=url_href).count()
            if count == 0:
                headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64) '
                                         'AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko)'
                                         ' Chrome/60.0.3112.101 Safari/537.36'}

                request = Request(url_href, callback=self.parse, headers=headers, dont_filter=True)
                request.meta['url'] = url_href
                request.meta['text'] = text
                request.meta['media_url'] = media_url
                request.meta['time'] = time
                yield request
    sleep(5)
    driver.close()
```

**Parse Function Code:**

```
def parse(self, response):
    print(response, "RESPONSE===========================")
    summary_list = []
    story_url = response.meta['url']
    story_title = response.meta['text']
    media_url = response.meta['media_url']
    time = response.meta['time']
    try:
        dummay_news = News.objects.get(url=story_url)
        return
    except News.DoesNotExist:
        dummay_news = News()
        story_p_tags = response.xpath("//div[contains(@class,'story__content')]/p/text()")
        for p in story_p_tags:
            summary_list.append(p.extract())

        dummay_news.source = 'xyz'
        dummay_news.time = time
        dummay_news.title = story_title
        dummay_news.url = story_url
        dummay_news.set_summary(summary_list)
        if media_url:
            dummay_news.media_url = media_url
        dummay_news.save()

    yield dummay_news
```

***Scraper* gets stuck after this request**:

```
2018-05-02 13:47:18 [selenium.webdriver.remote.remote_connection] DEBUG: Finished Request
2018-05-02 13:47:18 [selenium.webdriver.remote.remote_connection] DEBUG: GET http://127.0.0.1:35091/session/657a553b268a671e8117dba401ceeee8/element/0.8764352324704219-426/attribute/alt {"id": "0.8764352324704219-426", "name": "alt", "sessionId": "657a553b268a671e8117dba401ceeee8"}
2018-05-02 13:47:18 [selenium.webdriver.remote.remote_connection] DEBUG: Finished Request
2018-05-02 13:47:18 [selenium.webdriver.remote.remote_connection] DEBUG: GET http://127.0.0.1:35091/session/657a553b268a671e8117dba401ceeee8/element/0.8764352324704219-226/attribute/title {"id": "0.8764352324704219-226", "name": "title", "sessionId": "657a553b268a671e8117dba401ceeee8"}
2018-05-02 13:47:18 [selenium.webdriver.remote.remote_connection] DEBUG: Finished Request
```

Further no callback function gets initiated and it stuck forever after this error occurs. 
Any help is highly appreciated, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

you're doing `driver.close()` in your start_requests() method. However, I think you should not close selenium driver too early. Remove this line and try.

Answer (score 0):

Don't close your driver in `start_requests`.
you can close and quit it like this

```
def __del__(self):
    self.driver.close()
    self.driver.quit()
```

And your `yield dummay_news` should be in `except`

```
try:
    dummay_news = News.objects.get(url=story_url)
    return
except News.DoesNotExist:
    dummay_news = News()
    story_p_tags = response.xpath("//div[contains(@class,'story__content')]/p/text()")
    for p in story_p_tags:
        summary_list.append(p.extract())

    dummay_news.source = 'xyz'
    dummay_news.time = time
    dummay_news.title = story_title
    dummay_news.url = story_url
    dummay_news.set_summary(summary_list)
    if media_url:
        dummay_news.media_url = media_url
    dummay_news.save()

    yield dummay_news
```

Comment: thanks for pointing out this issue. I have made changes you said but its not realted to the question.